# Best File format to import data into remote MySQL from a local software

Tags: mysql, file, import, format

Let me clarify what I am exactly looking for. I am building a dynamic website for a school on php mysql platform which will require certain data to be updated from the local offline software that the school uses. I am in touch with the software provider and the software provider is ready to provide the data in whatever format is required by me.

So what would be the best format, the easiest, fastest and more reliable. Would it be csv, excel, etc. Mostly I will need the student details, grades etc from the local database. What else will I require to take care of in case any of you have done a similar project?

Looking forward to replies.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is the easiest to handle. You don't even need to process it in PHP if you can get it in a format that MySQL can use with `LOAD DATA INFILE` if you have access to the database server itself.

Excel is not at all easy to import and can be mangled in all kinds of ways that aren't obvious. It's best avoided unless you absolutely need to support it.

If you're building a new application, I really hope you use a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) as a foundation. Some of these include modules for handling CSV data, saving you the trouble of having to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks that does help. Regarding popular php framework, which one would you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) has pushed to the forefront in the last while, so that's probably the best these days. It's well documented and supported. The idea of a framework is to provide all the boilerplate. There's no such thing as a "beginner" framework per-se, but there are some that might fit your requirements better than others. The more popular it is, the easier it will be to get support or find modules for it. [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) and [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) also worth checking out.